# How to split a string into 2 different variables based on a delimiter?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I split one variable into two using the split function.Now I want to store the split variable as 2 different variables.

For example, I split the string 'input' into 2 parts. Now I split the variable with the delimiter being a forward slash (/). I want to store the text which was before the slash as 'input_1' and the text after the slash as 'input_2'. How do I do this?

Please provide some code too, I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you split your String, it will return an Array. All you need to do is grab each element from the Array.

Note: this can be dangerous if you don't know what input you're taking in, consider checking the actual length of the result.

```
val input = "before/after"

// Split will return an array
val split = input.split("/")

val before = split[0] // First element
val after = split[1] // Second element
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're doing this:

```
var split = input.split('/')
var pre_input = split[0]
var post_input = split[1]
```

For the case, your input has only one slash.

Comment: You should only use `var` if you planned to modify the variable later. You should instead use `val` as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wish I could mark 2 answers as the right answer.